# Dplyr equivalent of SUM over PARTITION BY

Tags: r, dplyr, partition-by

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find the answer.

Here's my data:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c("a","a","a","b","b","c"), value=c(1,2,3,4,5,7))
df
#>   group value
#> 1     a     1
#> 2     a     2
#> 3     a     3
#> 4     b     4
#> 5     b     5
#> 6     c     7
```

I'd like a 3rd column which has the sum of "value" for each "group", like so:

```
#>   group value group_sum
#> 1     a     1         6
#> 2     a     2         6
#> 3     a     3         6
#> 4     b     4         9
#> 5     b     5         9
#> 6     c     7         7
```

How can I do this with dplyr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dplyr -

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(group_sum = sum(value))
```

Comment: Good simple code but this method fails to sum when there is NA. Any suggestion to improve this code?

Answer (score 3):

Nobody mentioned `data.table` yet:

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(df)

dat[, `:=`(sums = sum(value)), group]
```

Which transforms `dat` into:

```
   group value sums
1:     a     1    6
2:     a     2    6
3:     a     3    6
4:     b     4    9
5:     b     5    9
6:     c     7    7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
left_join(
  df,
  df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(group_sum = sum(value)),
  by = c("group")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it one step, but

```
df_avg <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(group_sum=sum(value))  
df %>% full_join(df_avg,by="group")
```

works.  (This is basically equivalent to @KeqiangLi's answer.)

`ave()`, from base R, is useful here too:

```
df %>% mutate(group_sum=ave(value,group,FUN=sum))
```

Comment: That `ave()` function is what I was looking for - thank you